# Application crashing on launch

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, release

My application that works flawlessly in Debug/Development mode, crashes on launch in Distribution (Enterprise Distribution Build). Here's the crash log:

> Incident Identifier: D03AA940-6D86-41E7-A90C-997C7C840570
>   CrashReporter Key:   f79cf5348f25235e81156465863880c9a213ba09 Hardware
>   Model:      iPhone7,2 Process:             EFC [1405] Path:
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9C9BAABD-1BD5-4684-894E-329C6A11CE9C/MyApp.app/MyApp
>   Identifier:          com.company.ent-myapp Version:             100
>   (0.1) Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native) Parent Process:
>   launchd [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDPfe.png)
>
> Date/Time:           2016-05-07 12:14:07.07 +0500 Launch Time:
>   2016-05-07 12:14:07.07 +0500 OS Version:          iOS 9.3.1 (13E238)
>   Report Version:      105
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000001, 0x000000012003d088 Triggered by Thread:  0
>
> Filtered syslog: None found
>
> Dyld Error Message: Dyld Message: Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire   Referenced from:
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/9C9BAABD-1BD5-4684-894E-329C6A11CE9C/MyApp.app/MyApp
>   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9C9BAABD-1BD5-4684-894E-329C6A11CE9C/MyApp.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire:
>   mmap() errno=1 validating first page of
>   '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9C9BAABD-1BD5-4684-894E-329C6A11CE9C/MyApp.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire'
>     /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9C9BAABD-1BD5-4684-894E-329C6A11CE9C/MyApp.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire:
>   mmap() errno=1 validating first page of
>   '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9C9BAABD-1BD5-4684-894E-329C6A11CE9C/MyApp.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire'
>     /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9C9BAABD-1BD5-4684-894E-329C6A11CE9C/MyApp.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire:
>   mmap() errno=1 validating first page of
>   '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Applicatio   Dyld Version: 390.7
>
> Binary Images: 0x100008000 - 0x10081ffff EFC arm64 
>   <202501eaffad3aa4a30e701306b22a26>
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/9C9BAABD-1BD5-4684-894E-329C6A11CE9C/MyApp.app/MyApp
>   0x12003c000 - 0x12006bfff dyld arm64 
>    /usr/lib/dyld

1. I've tried preparing the Enterprise Distribution build with `Enable Bitcode` `Yes` and `No`.
2. I've verified multiple times that the code signing and provisioning profiles are setup properly.
3. I have the latest/ renewed `Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority`.
4. I'm using cocoapods in my project, and I'm working with `Release` configurations, that are using `Pods-MyApp.release`. Note: I'm using cocoapods in my project for the first time. Incase it's relevant, content of my pods file are below for reference.

Contents of my `Podfile`:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!

target 'EFC' do

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK'

pod 'AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator', '~> 1.0'
pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 2.0'
pod 'ObjectMapper', '~> 1.2'

pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'UILoadControl'

end
```

I'm stumped. Any clue as to what's going on? How can I fix this and successfully prepare my enterprise build?

Maybe I'm missing something in cocoapods setup (for release/distribution), but I don't know what!?

**Edit**

The export dialog looks like this, if that makes any difference.

[image]

Comment: Are you using xcworkspace?

Comment: Yes, I'm using xcworkspace, as required by cocoapods.

Comment: is it working fine on simulator?

Comment: Yes, working find on simulator and device, when I run in Debug/Development mode.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a fresh install El Capitain with Cocoapods 1.0 installed. I've installed new created certficates and profiles. I've removed cocoapods and reinstalled it . The app runs fine with Simulator . App created without cocoapods runs fine when I build but any project with cocoapods will build fine but crash as soon as i open it. Please help . Note that I have another MacBook that was upgraded to El Capitain and I have no issues building Enterprise Apps. Thank s

Comment: @Mustafa omg I went through hell testing all suggestions online until I tried one last thing and it worked for me . Go to your keychain and remove certificate "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority" . I had two of them , one in login and one in system . I deleted both . None of them was expired but it was the issue. I downloaded a new one from here http://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer and I only had it in login . Try and let us know . Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-generated the Distribution CERTIFICATE, and profile. THIS resolved the issue for me!

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: I assume that you use a build configuration that is not called `Release` in the Enterprise build. Try to add a build config to the pod frameworks with the same name as the build config you are using for your Enterprise build.

Comment: I've tried using a new build configuration, and using existing "Release". Same results, in both cases. I must be missing something, but I don't know what.